# Sveltekit is not intercepting fetch call in handleFetch hook

Tags: javascript, svelte, fetch-api, sveltekit, svelte-3

I recently discovered the `handleFetch` hook in Sveltekit. Now I'm trying to use it to intercept calls to my backend (written in Go) but doesn't seem to work (unless I'm missing something).

The documentation reads:

> This function allows you to modify (or replace) a fetch request that happens inside a load or action function that runs on the server (or during pre-rendering).

I've got `src\hooks.server.js`:

```
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').HandleFetch} */
export async function handleFetch({ request, fetch }) {
    console.log("HERE IN --------> HANDLE FETCH HOOK")

    return fetch(request);
}
```

As you can see I'm just trying to make sure the hooks is called by printing a message on the terminal.

I've got a `load` function in `src\routes\records\+page.server.js`:

```
export async function load() {
    console.log("HERE IN LOAD")
    // const records = await getAllRecords(1, 10);
    const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/records?page=1&per_page=2`);
    const records = await response.json();
    console.log(await records);
    return records;
}
```

Although I see the `HERE IN LOAD` message and the response being printed I never see the message that indicates that the hook was hit.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `fetch` function that is provided to the `load` function as a prop.

```js
export async function load({ fetch }) { // destructure `fetch` from the first argument
    console.log("HERE IN LOAD")
    // const records = await getAllRecords(1, 10);
    const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/records?page=1&per_page=2`);
    const records = await response.json();
    console.log(await records);
    return records;
}
```

You can read more about which props are passed to `load` functions [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#public-types-loadevent).

Comment: Yes, that did work. Thanks Patrick. It's a bit of a let down, I was expecting to intercept any fetch. As you can see, my original call is to `const records = await getAllRecords(1, 10);` which lives in a separate file where I grouped all the API calls to the backend for `records`. That file structure won't work anymore,  either I change it or pass `fetch` into that `getAllRecords` call (which doesn't look neat to me)